# Get the list of APIs called on loading of a URL programtically

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

How can we, through python, retrieve the APIs that are being called by a webpage when it loads, under the 'Network' section when we do `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `I` to inspect the traffic of the webpage.

I tried the requests module, but we can only retrieve the page HTML but not the APIs that the webpage calls.
I also looked into selenium web-driver automation but had no luck.

```py
import requests

resp = requests.get('https://edition.cnn.com/2021/12/21/australia/australia-new-south-wales-covid-omicron-intl-hnk/index.html')
html_data = resp.content
```

Here, `html_data` only consists the page HTMl but no ingo on the APIs loaded as part of the page load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an implementation of based on selenium just for that called [selenium-wire](https://pypi.org/project/selenium-wire/). First install selenium-wire via the command

```
pip install selenium-wire
```

then for you page you can use this

```
from seleniumwire import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service("D://drivers//chromedriver.exe")
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)

driver.get('https://edition.cnn.com/2021/12/21/australia/australia-new-south-wales-covid-omicron-intl-hnk/index.html')

for request in driver.requests:
    if request.response:
        print(
            request.url,
            request.response.status_code,
            request.response.headers['Content-Type']
```